# Wrong computation in ifelse on factors

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a dataframe called `g1`. It has 3 columns that are factors:  `max_num`, `max_res` and `g1$bdest`. I have a number `N = 8`. I would like to create a new column with name `g1$WMA`. For each row: in case `g1$max_num > N/2` I would like `g1$WMA` to get the value `g1$max_res` otherwise - `g1$bdest`.
I used the following command, however I get a wrong computation:

```
g1$WMA = ifelse ( (( as.numeric(as.character(g1$max_num) ) )> (N/2)), g1$max_res, g1$bdest)
```

How can I correct it?

Comment: Please have a look at the first row:
  max_res max_num min_res min_num SPA bdest WMA
1  0 7 1 1 1 0 1
WMA should get 0 and it equals 1.

Comment: Since `g1$max_res` and `g1$bdest` are also factors, they are silently unclassed in ifelse statement. You should change them to characters and then to numerics as well

Comment: Sorry, I thought the other columns were numeric.